# Connecting to remote MYSQL from tomcat7

Tags: mysql, tomcat7, remote-access, jasperserver

I've been wrestling with this for the past few days. All I want to do is connect a jaspersoft server to a remote MYSQL server. I've tried everything I can find including:

commented `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` , also changed to `bind-address = ::1` - neither worked.

I've also tried adding my user to the mysql privileges: `GRANT ALL ON database.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` - no luck

I can also see that port 3306 is open:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Also, I cannot connect via the jasperserver dashboard via the browser.

Does anyone have any ideas I haven't tried?

Also, my jdbc driver is in the correct location.

Here's the error code from the jasperserver dash as well:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to 54.213.92.113:3306 : Connection refused at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.get(SQLExceptionMapper.java:136) at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.throwException(SQLExceptionMapper.java:106) at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:114) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.action.DataSourceAction.testJdbcDataSource(DataSourceAction.java:482) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at org.springframework.webflow.action.DispatchMethodInvoker.invoke(DispatchMethodInvoker.java:98) at org.springframework.webflow.action.MultiAction.doExecute(MultiAction.java:123) at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188) at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51) at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:77) at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188) at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145) at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:227) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545) at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:261) at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) at org.springframework.security.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:66) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.resumeExecution(Unknown Source) at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183) at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.StaticFilesCacheControlFilter.doFilter(StaticFilesCacheControlFilter.java:137) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:399) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.IPadSupportFilter.doFilter(IPadSupportFilter.java:67) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.JSSwitchUserProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(JSSwitchUserProcessingFilter.java:154) at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109) at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101) at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:411) at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105) at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53) at
```

Comment: are you able to connect to your mysql server using any mysql client.? Do you get any exceptions , which may contain info on what s happening?

Comment: just added the error form the jasperserver dash. Telnet doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MySQL server is only listening on localhost (127.0.0.1:3306) so you won't be able to connect to it from any remote host. You need it to listen on 0.0.0.0:3306 which is all IPv4 addresses. Try `bind-address=0.0.0.0`

Comment: Yup...I was actually about to answer that myself. I had actually tried changing the bind-address=0.0.0.0 in the past and it hadn't worked. However, I had forgotten to restart MYSQL. D-oh!